# Хранимка с uniqueidentifier параметром

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ado.net

Есть хранимка которая на вход принимает параметр типа uniqueidentifier

Значение параметра может быть примерно следующим:

> 1D4A12F7-D62C-3DBA-CAA5-FC674EC7A09B

В MsSQL Server Managment Studio я хранимку вызываю следующим образом:

```
EXEC    [dbo].[p_GetType]
        @TypeId = '{1D4A12F7-D62C-3DBA-CAA5-FC674EC7A09B}'
```

И всё ок, хранимка возвращает нужные результаты.

Вопрос: Как вызвать хранимку из кода на C# используя ADO?

Я пытаюсь задавать параметр для передачи следующим образом:

```
 SqlParameter par = new SqlParameter("@TypeId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier) { Value = "'{1D4A12F7-D62C-3DBA-CAA5-FC674EC7A09B}'" };
```

Но при вызове вылазит эксепшн сообщающий что string в uniqueidentifier не получается перевести.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Замените

```
Value = "'{1D4A12F7-D62C-3DBA-CAA5-FC674EC7A09B}'"
```

на

```
Value = new Guid("1D4A12F7-D62C-3DBA-CAA5-FC674EC7A09B")
```